# Installation of tensorflow-gpu 1.4 on cuda 9 and cudnnv7

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu on gtx 1050 with cuda 9 and cudnn v7 on windows 10. I have added all the environment variables. But I am getting the following error:
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_80.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable

Answer (score 4):

I just replied something very related [in this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47503155/4511978). Assuming you got the CUDA and CUDNN part, and for your specific question, it is indeed possible and easy to get TensorFlow 1.4 working with CUDA9+CUDNN7 on Python:

1. Visit [mind's repo](https://github.com/mind/wheels) and download the `wheel` file that suits your needs. Wheel files are precompiled Python packages and can be installed very easily with `pip`, which hopefully also works on windows without much trouble (I didn't test it, let me know if this works). If your desired package doesn't happen to be there, you can give a look to [this repo](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels) that the user [Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419116/yaroslav-bulatov) organized to see if you find what you look for. Thank you all for this effort, by the way!
2. Install the wheel with `pip`. Quick test:

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   x = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.ones([1,1,10,1]), tf.ones([1,5,1,1]), strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(x) # this should output a tensor of shape (1,1,10,1) with [3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3]
   ```

Note that some of mind's wheels require Intel's MKL library to be installed, as noted [here](https://github.com/mind/wheels/releases/tag/tf1.4-gpu-cuda9). Again, in the other SO post I referred to before I detail the instructions for installing it and making TF finding it on Linux (Linux users may want to check the post that I linked for more details on installing CUDA and CUDNN without root privileges). The official instructions to build it can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-dnn-part-1-library-overview-and-installation) (they seem to be only for Ubuntu, though).

Cheers,
Andres

Comment: very useful answer. i also think that [repo](https://github.com/gw0/docker-keras) is good.  
can you pls tell if launching TF1.4 is possible on CUDA 10 GPUs? i mean, do nvidia cards have backwards compatibility with older cuda libs?

Comment: Hi, glad it helped! I can confirm that CUDA 10 works with TF 1.14. In general you should be able to figure out your setup by triangulating the GPU model, driver and CUDA version

Comment: man, when someone talks about older lib versions, pls dont underestimate how old he means the lib is

Comment: Sorry, IDK why I thought that 1.14 was older than 1.4, I was kind of tired. I will let you know if I test it or figure it out

Comment: dear @ivan866, it seems that this answer has it perfectly covered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622526/4511978

Answer (score 1):

Current version of tensorflow i.e 1.4 supports cuda 8, thus 'cudart64_80.dll' of cuda 8 is missing. download cuda 8 and suitable cudnn, it will fix the problem