# How to build caffe2 with specified cuda and cudnn?

Tags: cudnn, caffe2

In the server,there are cudnn 7.0 and cuda 9.1 at /usr/local/cuda. I need to use detectron but it do not support cuda 9.1, so I need to install cuda 8.0.

I am using the server so I do not have root privilege.I tried to install cuda 8.0 and cudnn as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379792/install-cuda-without-root) the second answer do at /home/xx/caffe2.

Then I build the caffe2, but it use the cuda at /usr/local/cuda again.

So is there any way to use the cuda at /home/xx/caffe2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify environment variables when running the installation :

You can find a complete description of the environment variables in the `setup.py` file in the repository.

For example :

`CUDA_HOME=/home/xxx/cuda-9.1 python setup.py install`