# Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, driver

I just updated my graphics cards drives with

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
sudo apt install cuda-drivers-470
```

I decided to install them in this manner because they were being held back when trying to `sudo apt upgrade`. I mistakenly then did `sudo apt autoremove` to cleanup old packages. After restarting my computer for new drivers to get setup properly, I could no longer use GPU acceleration with tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
WARNING:tensorflow:From <stdin>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2021-12-07 16:52:01.771391: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-12-07 16:52:01.807283: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-12-07 16:52:01.807973: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-12-07 16:52:01.808017: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-12-07 16:52:01.808048: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-12-07 16:52:01.856391: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-12-07 16:52:01.856466: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-12-07 16:52:01.857601: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create symlinks inside of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory. I found it by:

```
$ whereis libcudart
libcudart: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so /usr/share/man/man7/libcudart.7.gz
```

Within this folder you can find other versions of those cuda libraries. Then create symlinks like this. Your specific version that you are linking to might be slightly different.

```
$ sudo ln -s libcublas.so.10.2.1.243 libcublas.so.11
$ sudo ln -s libcublasLt.so.10.2.1.243 libcublasLt.so.11
$ sudo ln -s libcusolver.so.10.2.0.243 libcusolver.so.11
$ sudo ln -s libcusparse.so.10.3.0.243 libcusparse.so.11
```

Now your GPU should be detected.

```
import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available()
WARNING:tensorflow:From <stdin>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2021-12-07 17:07:26.914296: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-12-07 17:07:26.950731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-12-07 17:07:27.029687: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-12-07 17:07:27.030421: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-12-07 17:07:27.325218: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-12-07 17:07:27.325642: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-12-07 17:07:27.326022: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-12-07 17:07:27.326408: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 9280 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
True
```

This method works because these cuda libraries are similar enough that even NVIDIA build them with symlinks often. If tensorflow is looking for `libcublas.so.11`, you can create a file with that name that just points to another version of libcublas that is already installed.

Comment: it also fixes the Could not load library libcublasLt.so.12. Error: libcublasLt.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Thanks a lot

Comment: @GelberthAmarilloRojas does not work for me with tensorflow 2.13 and cuda 11.8

Comment: @Nick Jagiella It works to solve the warning related with the libraries, you first find the libraries you have and then you create the simlinks to it

Answer (score 11):

Have you installed `cuda-toolkit`? The error indicates that version 11 of the libraries is not found. The problem is that the cudatoolkit and the cudnn version may be incompatible with your tensorflow version.

If you already installed the correct version of the toolkit, go directly to Step 5. (You can check the version with the command `nvcc --version`).

1. Download the installer from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-4-4-download-archive?target_os=Linux (this version is compatible with the driver `nvidia-470` you installed). The next steps are specific to the `runfile` option.
2. As you already installed `nvidia-drivers`, press `Continue` if this message appears.

   [image]
3. Accept the terms.

   [image]
4. Again, as you already installed the drivers, just disable the Driver option and press `Install`.

   [image]
5. Now you need to configure the paths for binaries and libraries. Using `find` command search for `nvcc` and `libcublas.so.*`:

   ```
   sudo find / -name 'nvcc'  # Path to binaries
   sudo find / -name 'libcublas.so.*'  # Path to libraries
   ```
6. Finally, add the next lines at the end of file `~/.profile` according to the paths you found above. Cuda was installed on `/usr/local/cuda-11.4` in my system.

   ```
   if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-11.4" ]; then
       PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
       LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
   fi
   ```

If updating `~\.profile` doesn't work, try to update `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` (in case you use `zsh` instead of `bash`).

7. Restart the computer.

Comment: I don't sudo priviledges in my HPS :(  is there a different solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379792/install-cuda-without-root
I found this question. Hope it can help you but, you will need the drivers installed with `sudo`, at least.