# how does one fix when torch can't find cuda, error: version libcublasLt.so.11 not defined in file libcublasLt.so.11 with link time reference?

Tags: pytorch, cuda

I get this error with a pytorch import `python -c "import torch"`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/dfs/scratch0/brando9/miniconda/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 191, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/dfs/scratch0/brando9/miniconda/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 153, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/dfs/scratch0/brando9/miniconda/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 382, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /dfs/scratch0/brando9/miniconda/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/../../nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublas.so.11: symbol cublasLtHSHMatmulAlgoInit, version libcublasLt.so.11 not defined in file libcublasLt.so.11 with link time reference
```

how does one fix it?

related:

- [Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70268140/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libcublaslt-so-11-dlerror-libcublaslt-so-11)
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/51080

Comment: In case you need cpu-only version of pytorch follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485213/7991462) answer

Answer (score 96):

Like eval said, it is because pytorch1.13 automatically install nvidia_cublas_cu11, nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu11, nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu11 and nvidia_cudnn_cu11. While I have my own CUDA toolKit already installed, I have the same problem.

In my case, I used `pip uninstall nvidia_cublas_cu11` and solved the problem.
I think the PyTorch team should solve this issue, since users often have their own CUDAtoolkit installed.

Comment: This is really the answer if you installed your own nvidia drivers/CUDA toolkit

Comment: Seconded, this is what worked for me.

Comment: whoooa +1000, def solved my issue on my vm that had cuda 11.3 pre-installed

Comment: thanks, it solved my issue with using pytorch in docker image gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu113 from https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs/choosing-container

Answer (score 31):

The error is from dlopen libcublas.so from `.../python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/nvidia/cublas/lib/`, which is the pip package "nvidia-cuda-runtime" install location.

`libcublasLt.so.11` is dynamically linked to `libcublas.so.11`. The problem is that when you have a different cuda runtime installation (usually in /usr/local/cuda), dlopen probably gets the wrong one. You can run `ldd .../python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublas.so` to check the actual path of `libcublasLt.so.11`, which is supposed to be the one under `.../python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/nvidia/cublas/lib/`

Workarounds:

1. Set env `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.../python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/nvidia/cublas/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when launching python. So that dlopen can firstly look for .so files in that directory.
2. Using older torch. It was since 1.13.0 torch pip install started using pip nvidia-* packages. Before that cuda libs are statically linked. That's why older torch pip install has no problem even if you have existing cuda install.

Comment: This solution worked for me like a charm. To summarize, you will find libcublasLt.so.11 linked to `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/`; by using LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib/:$LD_LIBRART_PATH` the issue if fixed.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why this works but this worked for me:

```
source cuda11.1
# To see Cuda version in use
nvcc -V
pip3 install torch==1.9.1+cu111 torchvision==0.10.1+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

but if you look through the git issue these might also work:

```
conda install -y -c pytorch -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.1 pytorch torchvision torchaudio

pip3 install torch+cu111 torchvision torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I think the conda one looks like the most robust because you can specify exactly the cudatoolkit you need, so I'd recommend that one.

Comment: Does anyone can explain why this work? And if there's a solution with pip requirements?

Comment: I have already nvcc==11.2 which I install to run tensorflow models (with no issues), what happens if I run these commands? Will me already existing cuda toolkit be messed up? Or is it safe to run?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to work on an images detection problem using yolov7, and I installed default dependencies as provided by yolov7 https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/requirements.txt, but when I tried even to check the help manual I got this error

> OSError: .../yolov7_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/../../nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublas.so.11: undefined symbol: cublasLtGetStatusString, version libcublasLt.so.11

Then I tried to install some other dependencies using the following command:
`pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113`
this's how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running on a cpu only compute, and this issue got solved when installing a cpu version of PyTorch. For example: http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.13.0%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error occurs in a conda env, which is because the conda env could not find cuda installation. I solved it actually by uninstalling the CUDA toolkit on the system so the conda env can use its own toolkit.