# CUDA runtime version vs CUDA driver version - what's the difference?

Tags: cuda, version, nvidia

The CUDA Runtime API exposes the functions

- `cudaRuntimeGetVersion()` and
- `cudaDriverGetVersion()`

(see detailed description [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART____VERSION.html)). I was sort of expecting the first one to give me "8.0" (for CUDA 8.0) and the second one to give me the same string as what I'd get from examining nVIDIA's GPU driver kernel module, e.g.

```
modinfo nvidia | grep "^version:" | sed 's/^version: *//;'
```

which on my system is `367.57`.

Now, the first call gives me `8000` - fine, just a weird way to say 8.0 I guess; but the second API call also gives me `8000`. So what do both of these mean?

The Runtime API documentation I linked to doesn't seem to explain this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The CUDA runtime version indicates CUDA compatibility (i.e.  version) with respect to the installed cudart (CUDA runtime) library.

The CUDA driver version (as reported here) reports the *same* information with respect to the driver.

This relates to the driver compatibility model in CUDA.  As I am sure you know, a particular CUDA toolkit version (i.e. CUDA runtime library version, nvcc compiler version, etc.) [requires a particular *minimum* driver level for proper use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820513/what-is-version-of-cuda-for-nvidia-304-125/30820690#30820690) of the codes compiled with that toolkit.

The CUDA driver version (as reported here) effectively reports *what CUDA version(s) can be supported* by the particular installed driver.

As you've already discovered, it does not report the actual numbered driver version.

There is no way (currently) to get the actual numbered driver version via the CUDA runtime or driver API.  I don't expect changes in the future here because the driver specifics are abstracted at the CUDA level - just as discovered here.

If you want to retrieve the numbered driver version programmatically, one way to do it would be to use [NVML](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlSystemQueries.html) (which is installed and provided by the GPU driver).

If you wish to see a change in CUDA, you can always [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911).

Comment: (sigh) I get it now. So, I can blame the confusing names, then... Thanks. You've given me a bit of work to do on [this](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers).

Comment: Also, how exactly do I interpret the 8000? Are the three lowest decimal digits a single 'minor version number', or is it something like 8.0.0 or 8.0.0.0? After all, the CUDA 8.0 release was named 8.0.44 last time I downloaded.

Comment: Study the `deviceQuery` cuda sample code for interpretation hints.  There is no sub-versioning here.  8000 = CUDA 8

Comment: I still don't get it. Can someone ELI5? How do I check both of these outside of code (is there a way via the command line for both?). Is there also a driver for the graphics card itself (so 3 things: CUDA runtime, CUDA driver, Nvidia drive), or just the 2 things?

Comment: 1. There is a GPU driver version.   Query it with `nvidia-smi`.  2. There is a CUDA compatibility version associated with the driver (but there is a 1:1 correspondence between a specific GPU driver version and its associated CUDA compatibility version).  The `nvidia-smi` tool bundled with recent drivers will display the CUDA compatibility version that they have.  3.  There is a CUDA runtime version, which would be associated with the runtime API you use to build a particular runtime API code.  You can query this with `nvcc -v` for example, or these last 2 things with `deviceQuery` sample code.