# Are CUDA_VERSION and CUDART_VERSION necessarily the same?

Tags: cuda, versioning, api-versioning, cuda-driver

The CUDA Driver API defines `CUDA_VERSION` (in `cuda.h`), and the CUDA Runtime API defines `CUDART_VERSION` (in `cuda_runtime_api.h`). However - `CUDART_VERSION` is not defined as `CUDA_VERSION` but directly as a number.

Are they always supposed to have the exact same value, or are there circumstances in which they might differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be the same observationally, but not linked.

As [you already know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589814/cuda-runtime-version-vs-cuda-driver-version-whats-the-difference) at *runtime*, the CUDA version can be different than the CUDART version.  Therefore (or, insofar as that answer describes) there is no connection between the two.

However, both `cuda.h` and `cuda_runtime_api.h` will be installed by a CUDA installer.  So with respect to what that installer installs, they will match.  The installer installs both a driver and a development environment where the CUDA (driver API) version and CUDA runtime API version match.  But later on that can change (if you update the driver, for example.)  That is to say, the runtime versions can change depending on subsequent install activity. In any event, the `cuda.h` installed by the CUDA toolkit installer and the `cuda_runtime_api.h` installed by the CUDA toolkit installer will be as installed by the toolkit installer.

`cuda_runtime_api.h` does not depend on `cuda.h`. For that reason, one define is not simply a define of the other.  You can build CUDA runtime API applications that don't depend on `cuda.h` (the `deviceQuery` sample code is an example) and so there is no reason for `cuda_runtime_api.h` to build a define based on something in `cuda.h` - that would require you to always include `cuda.h` whenever you include `cuda_runtime_api.h`, and the CUDA designers had no intention of that.

Comment: `That is to say, the runtime versions can change depending on subsequent install activity.`
I feel this sentence is a little contradictory under the context.
1. If the `subsequent install activity` means installing the CUDA toolkit, it is contradictory to the next sentence,
`But the cuda.h installed by the CUDA toolkit installer and ... will remain what they were, ...`.
2. If the `subsequent install activity` means updating the GPU driver, it is contradictory to itself `the runtime versions can change` because updating driver doesn't change the CUDA Toolkit(including the CUDA Runtime).

Comment: I've made some wording changes.  The toolkit installer can/will install both header files.  For each install instance, the header files will be of a version that matches the installer version.

Comment: `the CUDA version` in your answer means the driver API version(installed by NVIDIA driver), `CUDA_VERSION` in the question is just a define in the `cuda.h` header file(installed by NVIDIA Cuda Toolkit). 
`CUDA_VERSION` and `CUDART_VERSION` in the header files denote runtime API versions, independent of the driver API version.
Is it correct?