# tensorflow error. CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda

I got the error message:

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2018-08-14 14:35:53.739970: I         tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-08-14 14:35:53.948699: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:897] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-08-14 14:35:53.949210: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8755
pciBusID: 0000:00:05.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.11GiB
2018-08-14 14:35:53.949241: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-08-14 14:35:53.949419: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1494, in __init__
super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 626, in __init__
self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSession(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

Doing on the following environment.

- Tesla K80 GPU machine
- Ubuntu 16.04
- CUDA 9.0
- cudnn7=7.1.4.18
- Python 3.6.6
- tensorflow 1.10

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your GPU driver. CUDA 9.0 needs driver version 384.XX.

See here: [What is version of cuda for nvidia 304.125](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820513/what-is-version-of-cuda-for-nvidia-304-125/30820690#30820690)