# Old docker containers are not usable (no GPU) after updating the GPU driver in the host machine

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

Today, we updated the GPU driver for our host machine, and the new containers that we created are all working fine. However, all of our existing docker containers give the following error when running the `nvidia-smi` command inside:

> Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

How to rescue these old containers? Our previous GPU driver version in the host machine was `384.125` and it is now `430.64`.

### Host Configuration

`nvidia-smi` gives

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.64       Driver Version: 430.64       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-DGXS...  Off  | 00000000:07:00.0  On |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    39W / 300W |    182MiB / 32505MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-DGXS...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    39W / 300W |     12MiB / 32508MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100-DGXS...  Off  | 00000000:0E:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    40W / 300W |     12MiB / 32508MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100-DGXS...  Off  | 00000000:0F:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    38W / 300W |     12MiB / 32508MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1583      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           169MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`nvcc --version` gives

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

`dpkg -l | grep -i docker` gives

```
ii  dgx-docker-cleanup                         1.0-1                                           amd64        DGX Docker cleanup script
rc  dgx-docker-options                         1.0-7                                           amd64        DGX docker daemon options
ii  dgx-docker-repo                            1.0-1                                           amd64        docker repository configuration file
ii  docker-ce                                  5:18.09.2~3-0~ubuntu-xenial                     amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-cli                              5:18.09.2~3-0~ubuntu-xenial                     amd64        Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine
ii  nvidia-container-runtime                   2.0.0+docker18.09.2-1                           amd64        NVIDIA container runtime
ii  nvidia-docker                              1.0.1-1                                         amd64        NVIDIA Docker container tools
rc  nvidia-docker2                             2.0.3+docker18.09.2-1                           all          nvidia-docker CLI wrapper
```

`docker version` gives

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:13:50 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 03:42:13 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: how are you launching the container? (what command)

Comment: When creating the container, I used `nvidia-docker run -it --name <container name> <image name>` . But I tested with the new containers that we created, regardless of `nvidia-docker run -it` or `docker run -it --runtime=nvidia`, it works.

When entering the container again we use `docker exec -it <docker name>`

Comment: One workaround I find is to use `docker commit` to create an image out of your container, and then create a new container using this image. Then the `nvidia-smi` works again inside the new container. I wonder if there is a way to revive the existing containers without doing `docker commit`

Comment: Was this solved? I have a similar issue with 450.** -> 460.**

Comment: It is not solved yet. My current workaround is to export the containers as images. Then I create new containers using these images, and the new containers somehow works. But it is very time consuming and it also takes up a lot of disk space to store all these images.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. In my case, I had the line:

```
apt install -y nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

in my Dockerfile. Removing this line resolved the issue. In general, I would recommend using an [nvidia provided container](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda) compatible with the drivers on your local machine.