# How to use GPUs with docker drivers/not host drivers?

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I am trying to use the docker image with new drivers >460 for CUDA 11 but my host machine has cuda-10.

According to the image below (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) docker uses the drivers present in the host hence I am getting error as kernel mismatch required 450+ kernel version 418.

I have installed the drivers on my container. I there any way to use the bare metal gpus from the container itself and bypass the host drivers??

[image]

Comment: In a word, no.   CUDA must use the driver installed on the host. There is a CUDA compatibility method to do something like it, but it has a variety of requirements that have to be satisfied.  [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015346/can-i-run-a-docker-container-with-cuda-10-when-host-has-cuda-9/57023447#57023447) provides a summary, your question is arguably a duplicate of that. one.

Comment: with a more advanced container orchestration system like kubernetes, its possible to update the GPU driver in the host from an [operator](https://github.com/NVIDIA/gpu-operator)  However this doesn't change the fact that a running container that is using the GPU depends on the GPU driver installed in the host machine.