# CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

Got the DLC-GPU.yaml from here: https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/blob/master/conda-environments/DLC-GPU.yaml

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research$ conda env create --name dlc --file=DLC-GPU.yaml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages
gettext-0.19.8.1     | 2.9 MB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
ipython-7.18.1       | 989 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
jupyter_console-6.2. | 26 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
qtconsole-4.7.7      | 96 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
prompt_toolkit-3.0.7 | 12 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
geos-3.8.0           | 961 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
pango-1.45.3         | 361 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
shapely-1.7.1        | 390 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
pyzmq-19.0.2         | 438 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
nb_conda_kernels-2.3 | 26 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
notebook-6.1.1       | 4.0 MB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
harfbuzz-2.4.0       | 850 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
jedi-0.17.2          | 912 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
gstreamer-1.14.0     | 3.1 MB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
argon2-cffi-20.1.0   | 46 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
pyrsistent-0.17.3    | 89 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
ipykernel-5.3.4      | 179 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
nb_conda-2.2.1       | 32 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
cffi-1.14.3          | 223 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
glib-2.65.0          | 2.9 MB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
fribidi-1.0.10       | 103 KB    | ################################################################################################################################################################ | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: \ Enabling nb_conda_kernels...
Status: enabled

/ Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `EnableNBExtensionApp`.
Enabling notebook extension nb_conda/main...
      - Validating: OK
Enabling tree extension nb_conda/tree...
      - Validating: OK
Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `EnableServerExtensionApp`.
Enabling: nb_conda
- Writing config: /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/etc/jupyter
    - Validating...
      nb_conda 2.2.1 OK

done
Installing pip dependencies: / Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting deeplabcut
  Using cached deeplabcut-2.1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (400 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2020.6.20)
Collecting matplotlib==3.0.3
  Using cached matplotlib-3.0.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.0 MB)
Collecting numpy==1.16.4
  Using cached numpy-1.16.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.3 MB)
Collecting scikit-image
  Downloading scikit_image-0.17.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.5 MB)
Collecting scikit-learn
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.23.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ipython-genutils in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.0)
Collecting ruamel.yaml~=0.15
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.16.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.49.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.15.0)
Collecting tables
  Using cached tables-3.6.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting tensorpack>=0.9.7.1
  Using cached tensorpack-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (291 kB)
Collecting statsmodels
  Downloading statsmodels-0.12.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (9.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ipython in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (7.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (49.6.0.post20200814)
Collecting pyyaml>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
Collecting intel-openmp
  Using cached intel_openmp-2020.0.133-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (919 kB)
Collecting opencv-python~=3.4
  Downloading opencv_python-3.4.11.43-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (49.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.8.1)
Processing /home/mona/.cache/pip/wheels/db/37/b8/b3785332f8246f1306c2863553860ca65e1824fc4c8251c7f1/moviepy-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting patsy
  Using cached patsy-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (231 kB)
Processing /home/mona/.cache/pip/wheels/88/96/68/c2be18e7406804be2e593e1c37845f2dd20ac2ce1381ce40b0/easydict-1.9-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandas>=1.0.
  Using cached pandas-1.1.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.35.1)
Collecting click
  Using cached click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting imgaug
  Using cached imgaug-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (948 kB)
Collecting chardet
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: h5py~=2.7 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.10.0)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (88 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib==3.0.3->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.4.7)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting pillow!=7.1.0,!=7.1.1,>=4.3.0
  Using cached Pillow-7.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting imageio>=2.3.0
  Using cached imageio-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting tifffile>=2019.7.26
  Using cached tifffile-2020.9.22-py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)
Collecting networkx>=2.0
  Using cached networkx-2.5-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting PyWavelets>=1.1.1
  Downloading PyWavelets-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Using cached joblib-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (300 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml.clib>=0.1.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version < "3.9"
  Using cached ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (547 kB)
Collecting numexpr>=2.6.2
  Using cached numexpr-2.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (162 kB)
Collecting psutil>=5
  Using cached psutil-5.7.2.tar.gz (460 kB)
Collecting msgpack>=0.5.2
  Downloading msgpack-1.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (275 kB)
Collecting msgpack-numpy>=0.4.4.2
  Using cached msgpack_numpy-0.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting tabulate>=0.7.7
  Using cached tabulate-0.8.7-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorpack>=0.9.7.1->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyzmq>=16 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorpack>=0.9.7.1->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (19.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: traitlets>=4.2 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pygments in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pexpect>4.3; sys_platform != "win32" in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: decorator in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jedi>=0.10 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pickleshare in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: backcall in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.0)
Processing /home/mona/.cache/pip/wheels/12/36/1f/dc61e6ac10781d63cf6fa045eb09fa613a667384e12cb6e6e0/proglog-0.1.9-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting imageio-ffmpeg>=0.2.0; python_version >= "3.4"
  Using cached imageio_ffmpeg-0.4.2-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (26.9 MB)
Collecting pytz>=2017.2
  Using cached pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Shapely in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from imgaug->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.7.1)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wcwidth in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pexpect>4.3; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: parso<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython->deeplabcut->-r /home/mona/research/condaenv.i4wb4gx_.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.7.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml, psutil
  Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.3.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=44619 sha256=bb81132d4bd4786a05057991336e112ed3ff6dde5653560f264e447e3b2f0e9c
  Stored in directory: /home/mona/.cache/pip/wheels/5e/03/1e/e1e954795d6f35dfc7b637fe2277bff021303bd9570ecea653
  Building wheel for psutil (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for psutil (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for psutil: filename=psutil-5.7.2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=292666 sha256=2b7326dd5f5f648c6f167599c04470dc27949e7d56211052d7231aa9318db886
  Stored in directory: /home/mona/.cache/pip/wheels/2d/43/97/00701864a7bee6d9e1a52dd682537dcbf1d013d0e2e6f0c1f1
Successfully built pyyaml psutil
Installing collected packages: kiwisolver, cycler, numpy, matplotlib, pillow, imageio, tifffile, networkx, PyWavelets, scikit-image, threadpoolctl, joblib, scikit-learn, ruamel.yaml.clib, ruamel.yaml, tqdm, numexpr, tables, psutil, msgpack, msgpack-numpy, tabulate, tensorpack, pytz, pandas, patsy, statsmodels, pyyaml, intel-openmp, opencv-python, proglog, chardet, urllib3, idna, requests, imageio-ffmpeg, moviepy, easydict, click, imgaug, deeplabcut
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.1
    Uninstalling numpy-1.19.1:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.19.1
Successfully installed PyWavelets-1.1.1 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 cycler-0.10.0 deeplabcut-2.1.8.2 easydict-1.9 idna-2.10 imageio-2.9.0 imageio-ffmpeg-0.4.2 imgaug-0.4.0 intel-openmp-2020.0.133 joblib-0.16.0 kiwisolver-1.2.0 matplotlib-3.0.3 moviepy-1.0.1 msgpack-1.0.0 msgpack-numpy-0.4.7 networkx-2.5 numexpr-2.7.1 numpy-1.16.4 opencv-python-3.4.11.43 pandas-1.1.2 patsy-0.5.1 pillow-7.2.0 proglog-0.1.9 psutil-5.7.2 pytz-2020.1 pyyaml-5.3.1 requests-2.24.0 ruamel.yaml-0.16.12 ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.2 scikit-image-0.17.2 scikit-learn-0.23.2 statsmodels-0.12.0 tables-3.6.1 tabulate-0.8.7 tensorpack-0.10.1 threadpoolctl-2.1.0 tifffile-2020.9.22 tqdm-4.49.0 urllib3-1.25.10

done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate dlc
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(base) mona@mona:~/research$ conda activate dlc
(dlc) mona@mona:~/research$ pip install deeplabcut==2.2b8

(dlc) mona@mona:~/research$ ipython
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 12:42:55) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import deeplabcut as dlc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dc21562c90f> in <module>
----> 1 import deeplabcut as dlc

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeplabcut/__init__.py in <module>
     36 else:  # standard use [wxpython supported]
     37     mpl.use("WxAgg")
---> 38     from deeplabcut import generate_training_dataset
     39     from deeplabcut import refine_training_dataset
     40     from deeplabcut.generate_training_dataset import (

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeplabcut/generate_training_dataset/__init__.py in <module>
     16 else:
     17     from deeplabcut.generate_training_dataset.auxfun_drag_label import *
---> 18     from deeplabcut.generate_training_dataset.labeling_toolbox import *
     19     from deeplabcut.generate_training_dataset.multiple_individuals_labeling_toolbox import *
     20     from deeplabcut.generate_training_dataset.frame_extraction_toolbox import *

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeplabcut/generate_training_dataset/labeling_toolbox.py in <module>
     31 
     32 from deeplabcut.generate_training_dataset import auxfun_drag_label
---> 33 from deeplabcut.utils import auxiliaryfunctions
     34 
     35 # ###########################################################################

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeplabcut/utils/__init__.py in <module>
      4 from deeplabcut.utils.conversioncode import *
      5 from deeplabcut.utils.frameselectiontools import *
----> 6 from deeplabcut.utils.make_labeled_video import *
      7 from deeplabcut.utils.plotting import *
      8 from deeplabcut.utils.video_processor import *

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeplabcut/utils/make_labeled_video.py in <module>
     26 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     27 import numpy as np
---> 28 from matplotlib.animation import FFMpegWriter
     29 from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
     30 from skimage.draw import circle, line_aa

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in <module>
    735 # Combine ImageMagick options with pipe-based writing
    736 @writers.register('imagemagick')
--> 737 class ImageMagickWriter(ImageMagickBase, MovieWriter):
    738     '''Pipe-based animated gif.
    739 

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in wrapper(writerClass)
    118         def wrapper(writerClass):
    119             self._registered[name] = writerClass
--> 120             if writerClass.isAvailable():
    121                 self.avail[name] = writerClass
    122             return writerClass

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in isAvailable(cls)
    728     def isAvailable(cls):
    729         try:
--> 730             return super().isAvailable()
    731         except FileNotFoundError:  # May be raised by get_executable_info.
    732             return False

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in isAvailable(cls)
    425         Check to see if a MovieWriter subclass is actually available.
    426         '''
--> 427         return shutil.which(cls.bin_path()) is not None
    428 
    429 

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in bin_path(cls)
    722         binpath = super().bin_path()
    723         if binpath == 'convert':
--> 724             binpath = mpl._get_executable_info('magick').executable
    725         return binpath
    726 

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _get_executable_info(name)
    383             raise FileNotFoundError(
    384                 "Failed to find an ImageMagick installation")
--> 385         return impl([path, "--version"], r"^Version: ImageMagick (\S*)")
    386     elif name == "pdftops":
    387         info = impl(["pdftops", "-v"], "^pdftops version (.*)",

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in impl(args, regex, min_ver, ignore_exit_code)
    328                 output = _cpe.output
    329             else:
--> 330                 raise _cpe
    331         match = re.search(regex, output)
    332         if match:

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in impl(args, regex, min_ver, ignore_exit_code)
    323             output = subprocess.check_output(
    324                 args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
--> 325                 universal_newlines=True, errors="replace")
    326         except subprocess.CalledProcessError as _cpe:
    327             if ignore_exit_code:

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    409 
    410     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 411                **kwargs).stdout
    412 
    413 

~/anaconda3/envs/dlc/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    510         if check and retcode:
    511             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 512                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    513     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
    514 

CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

In [2]:
```

```
$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Just for sake of reproducibility in future, I am also dumping DLC-GPU.yaml here:

```
# DLC-GPU.yaml

#DeepLabCut2.0 Toolbox (deeplabcut.org)
#© A. & M. Mathis Labs
#https://github.com/AlexEMG/DeepLabCut
#Please see AUTHORS for contributors.

#https://github.com/AlexEMG/DeepLabCut/blob/master/AUTHORS
#Licensed under GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0
#
# DeepLabCut environment
# FIRST: INSTALL CORRECT DRIVER for GPU, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820513/what-is-the-correct-version-of-cuda-for-my-nvidia-driver/30820690
#
# Suggested by Jan Eglinger see https://github.com/AlexEMG/DeepLabCut/issues/112
#
# install: conda env create -f DLC-GPU.yaml
# update:  conda env update -f DLC-GPU.yaml
name: DLC-GPU
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip
  - tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
  - cudnn=7
  - wxpython<4.1.0
  - jupyter
  - nb_conda
  - Shapely
  - pip:
    - deeplabcut
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib.animation` requires `ffmpeg` for saving movies and `ImageMagick` for saving animated gifs.

See https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#install-requirements

Install them with your system package manager:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg ImageMagick
```

Comment: just a note that in my case ffmpeg was already installed and I only needed to install ImageMagick